# Telerik RadGrid horizontal scroll will pass one column

Tags: asp.net, user-interface, telerik

I have Telerik RadGrid which contains around 20 columns. At the beginning , I can see column 1 to column 8. Then I scroll horizontally to see other columns. Suppose I should now see column 9 to 17, but I see the columns 10 to 18. Column 9 is passed over and not shown. One column is missed. How can I adjust the scrolling properties of Telerik to avoid this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the properties that are set for RadGrid. When it comes to scrolling, there are several things that needs to be considered.

For example, if scrolling is enabled along with Static headers, the columns must define a static width using HeaderStyle Width. See [Scroll with Static Headers](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/functionality/scrolling/scroll-with-static-headers).

Below you can find a working example.

RadGrid markup:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" Width="600px"
    OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource">
    <ClientSettings>
        <Scrolling AllowScroll="true" UseStaticHeaders="true" ScrollHeight="" />
    </ClientSettings>
    <MasterTableView>
        <HeaderStyle Width="150px" />
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

C# code behind. Binding dummy data to RadGrid

```
protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as RadGrid).DataSource = GetGridSource();
}
private DataTable GetGridSource()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < 20; colIndex++)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add(string.Format("Column{0}", colIndex + 1), typeof(string));
    }
    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < 5; rowIndex++)
    {
        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
        for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < dt.Columns.Count; colIndex++)
        {
            row[colIndex] = string.Format("Col {0}, Row {1}", colIndex + 1, rowIndex + 1);
        }
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    return dt;
}
```

Demo Video for the above code: [RadGrid hortizontal scoll with mutiple columns](https://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cFlj3zrauK)

Ultimately, if you could share the markup, I'd be able to give you a more accurate answer.